# new SDK manager (14) could not find the PATH to my java dir

Tags: android

I have a windows 7 computer and I try to upgrade to the new SDK (from 13
to 14). But the SDK manager told me he can't find the java path.
However All the other program could find it! I could run javac on
command line, and my eclipse could RUN my test java program. So it's
only the SDK who does not work anymore!  I am stucked; Could anyone
check it? Do you have the same problem?

Comment: lol, how do you know the SDK manager is male??????

Answer (score 0):

i believe there is a work around
like pressing back, then forward again
it should let you pass that

i have always gotten this message, and always do the steps above, without problems or further tweaking

Comment: For me it doesn't work. but thanks for your answer. I did  a backspace and after a white space are  there  the good keys?

Comment: not sure what you mean by your last sentence.  maybe post a screen shot but im talking about the install wizard.  clicking on the back button.  not the back key. then clicking the next button (simply going back one page then forward (you would do this when the error comes up saying it cant find java))